# System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData() returns "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden error "

Tags: c#, webclient

I am using `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadData()` method and this works on localhost but; when I load my code on server I get this error message :

> *The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden error*

Here is my code:

```
System.Net.WebClient objWebClient = new System.Net.WebClient(); 
byte[] bresim = objWebClient.DownloadData(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteUrl"]);
System.Drawing.Image imgPhoto = byteArrayToImage(bresim);
```

Help me out please
Thanks

Comment: you might want to add authentication header with the request.

Comment: HTTP error 403 simply means that the server you contacted just responded with a *"No, i do not give you what you want."* Unfortunately, it does not tell you the reason why. It may be the queried resource is not available on the server (unlikely, but possible), it may be the server configuration prevents you from accessing the resource (very likely: authentication or rule based access), it may be that the server is unhappy with some other data bits of the request being wrong or missing...

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue. Ok in Local, wrong in Production.
Solved changing this parameter in the Application Pool:

Advanced settings > Process Model > Load User Profile = true